# I can't get Javascript Intellisense XML Comments to work completely in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

First off, I'm not a Javascript programmer, but I do have JS programmers who report to me.

I'm trying improve how we work by getting the Javascript Intellisense features added to VS2008 to work.

Specifically, right now I'm trying to figure out how to add a semblance of strong typing to complex data structures.

So far, I'm come up with this:

```
GetDateTimeResponse = function GetDateTimeResponse() {
/// <summary>The return value from GetDateTime</summary>
/// <field name="CurrentDateTime" type="String" mayBeNull="false">The current date time, ISO8601 format UTC</field>
/// <field name="ListOfStrings" type="Array" arrayType="String" mayBeNull="true">An array of strings</field>
/// <field name="SubTypeList" type="Array">An array of complex types</field>
/// <field name="AnInteger" type="Number" integer="true">An integer</field>
/// <field name="AFloat" type="Number">A float</field>
};

GetDateTimeResponse.prototype = {
    CurrentDateTime: "",
    ListOfStrings: new Array(),
    SubTypeList: new Array(),
    AnInteger: 0,
    AFloat: 0.0
};
```

That's an experimental "class" to handle the response from a test SOAP/JSON service.

The WSDL references a schema which contains what is (supposed to be) a matching type:

```
<xs:element name="GetDateTimeResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CurrentDateTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name="ListOfStrings" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="SubTypeList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="IDFIeld" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element name="DisplayName" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="AnInteger" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="AFloat" type="xs:float"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

We use jQuery to communicate with the service, I'd like to write helper methods that take and return objects of that "type".

It kind of works. If I create js file, `/// <reference/>` the file containing that definition then this code works to an extent:

```
var bob = new GetDateTimeResponse();

bob.CurrentDateTime = "";
```

Now, on that I get intellisese for the Class name (`GetDateTimeResponse`), the Field names (`CurrentDateTime`, etc) and I get decriptions for the fields from the  comments.
But I don't get anything for the type, mayBeNull, arrayType and integer attributes. If I add a parameter to the contructor, and use the `<param>` comment, name, type and the descriptions work.
But integer, mayBeNull, etc, still don't do anything.

Any ideas?

Does this even work in VS2008?

Is there anyway to name a "Type" other that Object, Number or String (I'd like to have the intellisense do Arrays of Types)

Unltimately this is all so we can generate a javascript client to a web service with working intelisense.

My references for this are:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx